# Mass email tracking bounces,opens,clicks

Tags: email, tracking

Most services offered online today that claim to "track" e-mails,But every one using image.

**Is there any way to track the mail?**

most of the mail servers blocking the images, after clicking the "download image" they show images,this is not exact tracking.(most of the peoples not like to download the images)

I'm searching other ways.

how this is work with out downloading image
img src="www.mysite.com/?promo=offer1">

Comment: It is deplorable you want to invade the privacy of people. They have a human right to read their mail without you knowing where and when.

Comment: A "human right"? Oh please.....

Comment: If people want to respond to your email, they will. Since your email is most likely advertising for something they don't want, you shouldn't be surprised that they don't feel like responding. Using underhanded tricks to get an response from your unwanted spam may not be a violation of human rights but it demonstrates gross disrespect for the wishes of your potential customers. Knowing you do this, as a customer, I'd go to great lengths to avoid doing business with you.

Answer (score 3):

You could request a read receipt, but again no guarantee of it being sent.

In short - no there is no way to track an email itself once it has left your local MTA.

If this is for a web promotion, the usual thing is to add a promo identifier to any links back to your website (e.g. "www.mysite.com/specialoffer1" or "www.mysite.com/?promo=offer1") so you can see who has visited as a result of receiving the email.